# Word find/replace: add space to postal code with wildcards

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2003, wildcards

Using the “Find and Replace” dialog in Microsoft Word 2003,
I want to search a list of addresses for postal codes (Canadian) that do not have a space in them, e.g.,

```
M2N3X6
L4C2A9
K5G1S7
```

and put a space in the middle:

```
M2N 3X6
L4C 2A9
K5G 1S7
```

This should be simple, but I am having a bit of trouble with the "replace with" part:
I've figured out that in the Find field I enter `[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]`,
but in the Replace box, how do I add the space in the middle, retaining the characters that are there?
I thought it would be something like `\1\2\3 \4\5\6`, but that's not working

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This may be a better question for StackOverflow.com instead (which is about programming). What language are you using, and can you post the replace code in your question?

Comment: Are those (faulty) postal codes always exactly six characters long? Are they in a new line every time?

Comment: Not programming- just using MS Word 2003 on a document with about 30 pages of address labels-

Comment: ie:
Mr. John Doe
123 Any St.
Toronto, ON  M2N3X5

Comment: Yes, postal codes always 6 characters long - or I guess 7 with the space.  They are usually on the same line as the city, Province

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The \1 etc. replace expressions, and in order to specify that something is an expression, you enclose it in (). So you need

```
([A-Z])([0-9])([A-Z])([0-9])([A-Z])([0-9])
```

Then

```
\1\2\3 \4\5\6
```

should work. I think there is a limit on the number of expressions you can have (9, perhaps)

Comment: Or, more simply, replace `([A-Z][0-9][A-Z])([0-9][A-Z][0-9])` with `\1 \2`. (And, D’oh! I don’t know why I didn’t find that.)

Answer (score 0):

I can’t find any way (in Microsoft Word’s “Find and Replace” dialog)
to do full sub-regex replacement, the way you can in programs like `sed`. 
But I did find a multi-step solution to your problem. 
First, identify a string that does not appear in your data and does not contain
any characters that are special in Word’s “Find and Replace” (e.g., ‘`@`’ or ‘`#`’). 
(Alternatively, use them but escape them.) 
It can be a single character, like ‘`|`’, so long as it doesn’t appear in your data. 
I’ll assume that you’ve chosen “`|`”.  Now,

1. Do a search for `[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]` and replace with `^&|`. 
   This will tag each non-conformant postal code with a trailing “`|`”.
2. Search for `[0-9][A-Z][0-9]|` and replace with  `^&` (with a leading space). 
   This inserts the space where you want it.
3. Then search for all occurrences of `|` and replace with nothing.

You can do this without using wildcard mode:

1. `^$^#^$^#^$^#` → `^&|`.
2. `^#^$^#|` →  `^&`                (or even `^?^?^?|` →  `^&`).
3. `|` → nothing.

Note that `^$` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z]`,
so if your situation is case-sensitive, I guess you need to use the “wildcards”.

Comment: Excellent- don't know what sub-regex means I'll have to look it up- but this worked for me! Thank you

Comment: It’s just a term I made up to refer to using codes like `\1` to include a substring of what you found (using a regular expression) in the replacement. (In contrast to `^&`, which Word uses to include the _entire_ matched string.)

Answer (score 0):

Super simple way:  use the "Text to Columns" function in Excel and then use the CONCATENATE formula to recombine with a space in the middle. The formula would be =CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1)